# DAX Expression for calculating end of every year

Tags: date, calendar, powerbi, dax

I am looking for DAX expression to show me monthly figure for last financial years. Here is an example of the information;

The figure is accumulated since the starting of 31 Jan 2017 or earlier which I have no information. The data I have does not have a monthly view but Year to Date (YTD).

How could I structure the DAX so that it would be able to find out what is the figure for the month.

For example, Jan 2017 $2,000 , Feb 2017 $5000 (included figure from Jan 2017), March 2017 $8000 (included Jan 2017 and Feb 2017).

How can it be done to have the monthly view ?

Date............. Balance Sheet Amount.......View

31-Dec 2017................24,000.......................YTD   *1

31-Jan 2018................24,010.......................YTD   *1

28-Feb 2018................24,310.......................YTD   *1

31-Dec 2018................30,000.......................YTD   *2

31-Dec 2019................31,000.......................YTD   *3

31-Dec 2020................40,000.......................YTD   *4

30-June 2021................5,000.......................YTD   *5

Comment: You only want to add ending balance in Dec previous year or all the previous year?

Comment: i want to add all previous year`s december value and also current month`s value.

Comment: What do you mean by current month balance? can you show your expected output from the above sample data?

Comment: So I want to add up all previous years figure and current month (today`s is Jun 2021), will be sum of *1, *2, *3, *4, *5

For current month, i figured out  
CALCULATE(
        SUM(
            bs[amount]),
            MAX('Date'[Date])
            )

Comment: Do your previous year data contain other month balance than Dec only? Your current year data will include previous month balance also?

Comment: current data I have is only December 2020 and yes, the figure is accumulated from Jan - Dec 2020 which including previous month`s balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your current table does not contain previous balance, then it will be easier to obtain the current month movement with the following formula:

```
Current Month = Sheet1[YTD Bal] - 
                    CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[YTD Bal]),
                    FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[Index] = EARLIER(Sheet1[Index]) - 1))
```

Before you start the dax calculation, you will need to add `index column` first and here is the output:

[image]